# Using Log-Linear Regression to calculate the growth rate

Tags: logarithm, log-linear

I am learning the formula of growth rate and how to calculate this
Growth rate is $y = a * (1+x) ^ b$

Log-linear regression: $log y = log_a + b * log (1+x)$
Then b is considered as coefficient

What I dont understand the growth rate then compute as $10^{b}-1$. I dont know how to get the growth rate $10^{b}-1$ from the above formula

Could someone please help me to explain

Example: I am going to calculate the growth rate of revenue of a company as below
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "final growth rate"?  If we understand $x$ to be a time and $y$ to be a growing amount, its rate of growth varies.  What value of $x,$ then, might correspond to "final"??

Comment: Hi Whuber, Sorry I might describe not clear enough so now I edit my post and add some more information, please could you read again and hope you can help to explain me how  the growth rate 10^b-1 come up? Yes x is a time

Comment: The correct model for estimating growth rates is $y = a \exp(b x)$ (or, if you prefer, $y = a 10^{bx}$).

Comment: Hi Whuber, thanks for your reply.  could you please send me some basic knowledge of this formula so i can learn and understand. Thanks again

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22exponential+growth%22